# How to set relation in laravel with two ids?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, rdbms

I have these two tables:

```
product
- id
- name

favorites
- id
- product_id
- user_id
```

So, a user can add product to favorites only once. How can I set up this relation something like the following?

```
public function favorites() {
    return $this->hasOne(Favorite::class, 'user_id', 'product_id')
}
```

So, I want to use both `product_id` & `user_id` such that the query would return proper result as per the following:

> Get me the wishlist of user with id `1` and product with id `13`!

Comment: your approach is right, `favorites` will be your bridge table between `User` and `Product`. Second, you have to check explicitly for an existing product. If it exists in favorites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like that:

in favourite Model class:

```
public function product(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
public function user(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

In Product Model Class:

```
public function favorites(){
 return $this->hasMany('App\Favorite');
}
```

In User Model Class:

```
public function favorites(){
 return $this->hasMany('App\Favorite');
}
```

Comment: you can then fetch your required result something like this if i am not wrong: `$user->favorites()->where('id',1)->product()->where('id',13)`

Answer (score 1):

The user may have many favorites, so in `Class User`

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Favorite');
}
```

**Class Favorite**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

If you have user you can

```
$userFavProducts = $user->favorites;

$product2 = $user->favorites()->where('product_id', 2)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

**Favorites Model**

```
public function product(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id');
}
public function user(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```